Windows: Impact of encrypting a hard drive that has IIS apps running on it already?
My org wants all data at rest encrypted.  So if we encrypt a whole existing Windows hard drive for a web server that is already running Microsoft IIS web apps, what will be the impact?  They will all break?  They will run slower?  You have done this before and it works with no problems?

Modern encryption systems like Bitlocker are transparent at run-time. So your applications will not even recognize that all data is encrypted if you chose the correct encryption system. Also CPUs have AES-NI instruction which can encrypt/decrypt several hundred MB per second with a desktop CPU a server CPU should be even more powerful considering it was designed to handle TLS encryption.

Normally there is basically no impact, encrypted hard drives are a class of hard drives that are self-encrypted at the hardware level and allow for full disk hardware encryption while being transparent to the user. These drives combine the security and management benefits provided by BitLocker Drive Encryption with the power of self-encrypting drives. By offloading the cryptographic operations to hardware, encrypted hard drives increase BitLocker performance and reduce CPU usage and power consumption.
